# "Engineer at the Quality Assurance Department" vs. "Engineer of the Quality Assurance Department"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do we use? Which one is better here?

> John Smith, Process Engineer **at** the Quality Assurance Department.
>   John Smith, Process Engineer **of** the Quality Assurance Department.
>   John Smith, Process Engineer **in** the Quality Assurance Department.

This is from a table in an MS Word document. The column lists the names of employees who took part performing a particular task. Jonh Smith works in the QA Dept., another employee works for the same company, but in the Production Department, and so on.

I know that if it were the name of a company, not division, then we would use **at**. But maybe **of** is allowed (or even preferred) when we talk of a division or department.

Comment: @JavaLatte - ah! It never occurred to me. I'll add it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal choice is "**in** the department".

But if there is only one person in the role, then it could be **of**.

...an engineer in the department

...Lead Engineer of|in|for the department

but "head **of** the department". We don't ever say "head **in** the department", but we could say "head *of communications* in the department".

So, if we were to encounter the phrase "Process Engineer of the department", we might reasonably assume that Process Engineer is a role occupied by a single person, comparable to Lead Engineer. That would be the implication of **of**. For example, there might be a law governing pharmaceutical manufacturing facilities, say, which mandates that the QA Department designate a Process Engineer.